# A Newer Version of LXDE on the RPi 3

Tags: pi-3, lxde

Where can I find LXDM or LXDE version 9.9.1 or 10? I haven't been able to find a working tarball online.

Comment: There is no such version of either thing.   The [base components of LXDE in Raspbian jessie are 0.99.1](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/l/lxde-common/).   If you would like this question re-opened, please put together something coherent.

Comment: @goldilocks: If you run `apt-cache policy lxde` it displays version `6 0`.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Try `apt show lxde-common`.  Looking at wikipedia there seems to be a few different branches and weird numbering.  Like supposedly "stable" is 0.10, but that's *LXqt*.  0.99 is obviously a much higher number (no, it does not go 0.99, 0.10), yet also a year older --  but that's the GTK one I presume.  As for LXDM, its versioning is probably independent.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the tarballs you've downloaded aren't working for you because they're compiled for `x86` processors. The RPi (all versions) are running an `ARM` processor which is fundamentally different. If you'd like a further explanation of that, our blog has [an entry](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/140986024839/installing-applications-on-a-raspberry-pi-running) about it.

If you don't want to use the version in the Repos, you'll need to install from the source. This isn't going to be a particularly easy or quick process, but you can do it with a relatively small learning curve. We also have a blog [entry](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/141348857424/tmux-101-installing-from-source) on that. It's on Tmux, but the principles are the same.

The LXDE [download page](http://lxde.org/download/index.html) lists where there git repository is. You'll need to clone that repo, build the source, and then install it.